# How to save only those records where data is added and not all the records

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ajax

Suppose i have  a list of 10 product names and in right hand side to each product name, there is  text box to enter the quantity. Suppose out of 10 products, I enter quantity for only 2 , then my requirement is to save only these 2 records and not all the 10.

Please suggesting using java script and mobile J query, as i need it for an android application development.

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: What you have tried so far ? Provide us some code so we can suggest you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parseInt on all the values:

```
function checkValue(value)
{
    return parseInt(value) >= 0;
}
```

I put zero because you probably also want to ignore orders of zero quantity.

Comment: how can I determine, how many number of products have quantity =0? How to write that loop in jQuery, so that i can know the total no of products with qunatity as 0 ?

Comment: true. i changed the  function to also include values of zero, now only invalid entries such as blank fields will be eliminated and the zeros will be included in the data outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you can first have a default value for all the fields, which changes when the field is edited. Then, when the submit button is pressed, you can have a javascript code run instead of the normal submit operation which checks each field for its default or blank value, and using conditional loops then you can save the fields you wish to save.

Comment: Use http://www.w3schools.com to get the code for all of these. Comment below for specific snippets if you want.